# Female uniforms and colored panties in Star Trek TOS

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-uniforms

In Star Trek TOS you very frequently get glimpses of the female crew's panties under their short skirt uniforms. I've noticed they are always a matching color.

This makes me wonder - were the matching panties in fact an official part of Starfleet uniform?

[image]
[image: blue panties]

Also, was there any point in Star Trek TOS where a female crew member wore anything **except** a mini-skirt and matching panties? If not, how long was the period during which the Federation required this of its female crew (it would've been after Star Trek Enterprise and before Star Trek TNG, I think)?

Comment: @amarillo OK I added a better photo. While I can see why you'd think it's a skort because they are conservative ("granny") panties, like what cheerleaders wear, the difference is that if it were a skort there would be square shorts with a wrap-around skirt sewed partly over them. But you can see in the pics those are definitely form fitting panties.

Comment: @amarillo They come up with some interesting ways of explaining oddities in Star Trek TOS, for instance the virus that caused Klingons of that era to look like pale-skinned humans. I was thinking that in some book, animated series, or series I didn't watch (i.e. Voyager and DS9) they make have made up a way of explaining this period and added details about it. It's in pretty stark contrast to the rest of Star Trek and all other military uniforms.

Comment: Now I know why this SE site is called "Science Fiction & *Fantasy*" ...

Comment: "Also, was there any point in Star Trek TOS where a female crew member wore anything except a mini-skirt and matching panties?" - I think this sub-question should be split up into its own, separate question. (For the usual reason: With several questions in one SciFi SE question, you might get different answers on different of your questions. Yet, you will only be able to select exactly one answer as accepted/correct.)

Comment: How is this post *not* dirtier than it is?

Comment: All my life I had assumed that they weren't panties, that they were somehow part of rhe skirt, like an old-style swimsuit. This question blows my mind. I had no idea TOS was so PG-13. If my parents had known at the time, they would never have let me watch it - and that was the ONLY tv show we were allowed to watch for a year or two.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Yes**

The Franz Joseph uniform patterns from the Star Trek Technical Manual show that matching panties are a part of the normal female duty uniform. [full tech manual](http://www.cygnus-x1.net/links/lcars/sftm.php)

[image: uniform]

**EDIT**  Some of the confusion about the fabrication method (from the comments below) is addressed here [image]
Uhura's uniform and panties:

[image: Uhura]
[image: Uhura panties]

These uniforms were in use until the mid 2270's when the style changed to those in STTMP.

Dr. Elizabeth Dehner in "Where No Man Has Gone Before" wore a slightly different style of uniform that was worn with pants.

[image: Dr Dehner]

Number 1 and Yeoman Colt wore a similar style in "The Cage":

[image: number1]

Comment: That style worn by Dehner also appeared in "The Cage" pilot and "Charlie X".

Comment: @KyleJones: Yes I forgot about "Charlie X" and I edited my answer to include "The Cage".

Comment: I wonder why it specifies non-computer fabrication?

Comment: @Hack-R: The "Technical Manual" was 'accidentally' downloaded during the events of "Tomorrow Is Yesterday".

Comment: @Hack-R because you don't need to have a layout pattern at hand if the computer is fabricating the uniform, you only need it if you're making it manually.

Comment: Why would you? I mean, why make provisions for hand-crafted (rather than replicated) items to *be* official uniforms?

Comment: @JDługosz - But they didn't have replicators as such during TOS when these uniforms were standard.  Those were first seen in TNG.  ENT had the protein resequencer, but it only made basic food items, couldn't be used for clothing.  (Yes, I know they had miniskirts in the first season of TNG, but they were a very different design, and were quietly phased out.)

Comment: So a skirt is harder to print than a bun? I thought shapes and textures, just not living matter or microcircuits, was possible in TOS.  In the novels uniforms were dispensed from a fab unit of some kind.  But I suppose tjey could be cut and sewn by robots rather than printed in the final shape.

Comment: @JDługosz it seems to be a sensible idea to provide the ability to fabricate both by hand and via whatever technology is available.  Star fleet officers are likely to be found in isolated locations, and you don't want to have to end up being out-of-uniform if all your supplies are lost and your only fabricator is non-functional...

Comment: @JDługosz: Please see my edit above.  I hope this answers your question about fabrication methods.  Also note that the pattern is for non-computerized fabrication.

Comment: @Kaine That makes sense. I guess the hand crafted instructions were for emergency backup, or if you needed to re-program the computers, or most likely from a pre-production prototype.  I kind of wonder if the red and blue miniskirts / panties were every mixed and matched as a joke on the Enterprise.

Comment: The memo? I don't see what that has to do with fabrication.

Comment: @Jules when they were stranded in early 20th century Earth, they seemed more interested in being able to access the Tricorder and revewing records of the Guardian of Forever's viewing of history; if he was really trying to look up proper uniform patterns to take to a local taylor, that was not clear in the final edit.

Comment: @KyleJones: Is there a specific crew member that wore this older uniform style? Otherwise, I think the usual TOS uniforms were already worn in *Charlie X*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper About forty minutes into the episode a blond woman walked by Charlie and apparently didn't pay enough attention to him.  Charlie aged her about 50 years in a few seconds and she began to scream and cry.  She wore black pants and a gold top.

Comment: Oh, I have to see if I can get hold of a full sized copy of that pattern!  it would be fun for the next Comic Con :)

Comment: @JaneS: The pattern above is from the tech manual and is the only one that I know of.  You can download it from the like above and scale it up to any size.

Comment: The problem is that, while they're called "panties" they're actually more like modern "bloomers" or "briefs". Essentially, tights with no legs. They're commonly worn as parts of cheerleading uniforms. Whether there's an actual pair of panties worn under them is up to personal preference but they're designed to be outerwear...

Comment: @Catija: I think the technical term is 'granny panties".

Comment: @sfhq_sf I see they have centimetre markings on the pattern, I can use that as a baseline.  Besides, I'm way smaller than that median size 12, so I'd have to scale it anyway!

Comment: @sfhq_sf 'granny panties' usually refers to underwear. Catija is correct that these are not underwear.

Comment: @KyleJones: That's not the same uniform style. The woman you are referring to is wearing a variant of the regular female TOS uniform (plunging neckline with black collar) with trousers. In the two TOS pilots, a different uniform was still in use, one that had a coloured collar (a turtleneck for males and a roughly V-shaped smooth collar for females).